Wallet connection Issue after building an apk
Everyone.
I have developed an apk using React native expo and wallet connect.
It works well on the emulator but not after building.
Could you please tell me what the reason is?
When I am going to connect wallet using web3modal and wagmi, it is redirected to the metamask or trustwallet and connect modal should be appeared.
